# Ubercart shipping quotes silently fails on server migration

Tags: 7, ajax, ubercart, rules, migrations

I'm having a hard time figuring out why shipping quotes are failing after migrating to a new server.

I can clone the repo in my local machine, and shipping quotes come in fine. I can't find anything in the AJAX request/response headers that tells me why they're failing on the development site. They work on the live site. (It uses Drupal 7.7, while the development site is using Drupal 7.15.)

They work on my local machine (cloned from the same, updated the repository as development).

I get the following error messages on the watchdog log every time I try to get a shipping quote.

> Type: Rules
>   Location: /system/ajax
>   Referrer: /cart
>   Message: Unable to evaluate condition data_is

> Type: Rules
>   Location: /system/ajax
>   Referrer: /cart
>   Message: Unable to apply data selector order:delivery-address:country: Unknown data property delivery_address

I enabled the Rules UI module to view active/disabled rules. And it looks like some rules are based on parameters that no longer exist, perhaps due to updating the Ubercart module. This is confusing because I did the upgrade locally, and I did not find this issue.

These are the active rules with errors:

- E-mail an order update notification
- Machine name: uc_order_update_email_customer
- Weight: 0
- Error: Data selector order:order-status for parameter data is invalid

- Complete non-shippable order after payment received
- Machine name: uc_checkout_complete_paid
- Weight: 0
- Error: Data selector updated_order:order-status for parameter data is invalid

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I eventually traced the issue back a module called "UUID", which is required by Node Export.

Disabling UUID module solved my issues. The errors in the rules UI (admin/config/workflow/rules) simply went away.

Would love to know more about why this is. I don't need node export at the moment so it doesn't matter to me.